# preg_replace pattern, can't get it to work

Tags: php, regex

I have s tring that look like this

```
"143s (2m 23s)",
```

and I want to turn it in to this

```
"143",
```

I'm triyng to use preg_replace, but I cant get it to work

```
$file = "\"143s (2m 23s)\",";
$file = preg_replace("/[0-9]*(s*.*)/", "", $file);
echo $file;
```

Thank you

Answer:

```
$file = preg_replace('/("\d+)s.*(\",)/', '$1$2', $file);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
$file = "\"143s (2m 23s)\",";
$file = preg_replace('/("\d+)/', '$1",', $file);
echo $file;
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for, thank you
I did modivfy it 
$file = preg_replace('/("\d+)s.*(\",)/', '$1$2', $file);

Answer (score 0):

Use capturing groups to capture the characters you want for later reference.

```
$file = "\"143s (2m 23s)\",";
$file = preg_replace('~(\d+)s[^"]*~', '\1', $file);
echo $file;
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/hL2lE6/15)

Comment: I guess you wanna escape this guy `[s"]~` (3. char)